# Prestashop - Confirmacion de registro

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop1.7

Estoy trabajando con Prestashop 1.7 y me encuentro con la siguiente situación:

Necesito hacer que cuando un usuario se registre le aparezca un mensaje en la home (Que es donde actualmente esta redireccionando cuando el usuario se registra) confirmando que el usuario a sido creado con éxito para que pueda ser observado por la persona que se a registrado.

No se cuales son las funciones que hay que tocar para que ocurra esto.

Estoy usando el tema classic-rocket

Muchas gracias por adelantado

Comment: Cuando el usuario se registra se muestra un mensaje de confirmación de registro, puedes enviar un correo de confirmación de registro en Parametros de la tienda>Configuracion de clientes, activas la opcion; si el correo no se envia debes verificar en Parametros Avanzados>Email que tengas la configuración que funcione con tu hospedaje o VPS.

Comment: Justo ahora después de registrarse hace una redirección a la home. Después de eso tiene que mostrar un mensaje de confirmación que no esta mostrando

Comment: Favor edita tu pregunta y especifica si estas usando el Classic Theme o si es una template comprada.

Answer (score 0):

En el archivo
Classes/Form/CustomerPersister.php

en la linea aprox 204
en lugar de retornar la variable $ok;

```
        ## EN LUGAR DE ESTO SE IMPRIMIRA UNA VENTANA    // return $ok;
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.css"> <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script> setTimeout(function() {swal({
    title: "¡FELICIDADES!",     text: "¡Su cuenta fue creada, proceda a realizar sus pedidos!",
    type: "success" }, function() { window.location = "https:aqui la url de tu tienda para que redirecte al home";   });   }, 800);
    </script>  ';
```

Answer (score 0):

Te super recomiendo que descargues el modulo "Custom code module by ST-themes" veras, en el puedes agregar o modificar el codigo de tu pagina sin tocar ningún archivo interno, lo cual es genial por que no te arriesgas. Puedes agregar o modificar codigo CSS y Javascript (osea que puedes agregarle un alert), si sabes programar y aprendes manejar el modulo correctamente, puedes incluso modificar tu tema, a mi me ayudo bastante.

Adjunto imagen del modulo por si acaso...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]